# VkBufferCreateInfo-sharingMode-parameter issue

Tags: vulkan

Can anyone help me out with this runtime error:

```
14757395258967641292VUID-VkBufferCreateInfo-sharingMode-parameter(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - vkCreateBuffer: value of pCreateInfo->sharingMode (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkSharingMode enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: sharingMode must be a valid VkSharingMode value (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkBufferCreateInfo-sharingMode-parameter)
Objects: 1
[0] 0, type: 0, name: NULL
```

I am not unable to fix this.

My `VkBufferCreateInfo` looks like this:

```
VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreateInfo;

bufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;

bufferCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;

bufferCreateInfo.flags = 0;

bufferCreateInfo.size = sizeof(Vertex) * vertices.size();

bufferCreateInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT;

bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode - VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

bufferCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;

bufferCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;        

VkResult result = vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferCreateInfo, nullptr, &vertexBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the real code and not a transcription bug:

`bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode - VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;`

You want `=` not `-` ...